# No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' when building with apache ant

Tags: android, ant, android-manifest

My app targeted to the android API level 7 (2.1) and under the Eclipse all work good (resulting APK also works fine on the 2.1 devices). I try to build app with the apache ant and got this error. All of the solutions for the same problems tells me that I must set another target API level.

I want to simple ignore this attribute in manifest - as I find, in old devices it just ignored without any errors

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to have hardware acceleration with API level less than 11. [Check here](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/128042/android-30-hardware-acceleration) for more info.

Your best bet is to simply remove hardware acceleration attributes from your manifest.

Answer (score 2):

I declared

```
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

in manifest file. It resolved my problem. Hope it help others.