# Unable to build an Android Qt application

Tags: android, qt, deployment

I've installed the QtSDK, Android SDK & NDK on a new computer. I copied my project and didn't load my .pro.user.

I downloaded API10 SDK, set it in Qt Creator. The app compiles but I the apk creation fails. I get the following log:

```
-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 22.0.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for QtApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 2.3.3
[gettarget] API level:        10
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/marcin/proj/touchcatch/build-TouchCatch-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0-Debug/android-build/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/marcin/proj/touchcatch/build-TouchCatch-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0-Debug/android-build/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/marcin/proj/touchcatch/build-TouchCatch-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0-Debug/android-build/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/marcin/proj/touchcatch/build-TouchCatch-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0-Debug/android-build/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/marcin/proj/touchcatch/build-TouchCatch-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0-Debug/android-build/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/marcin/proj/touchcatch/build-TouchCatch-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0-Debug/android-build/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/marcin/proj/touchcatch/build-TouchCatch-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0-Debug/android-build/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for QtApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] Found 2 AIDL files.
     [aidl] Compiling 2 AIDL files.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] /home/marcin/proj/touchcatch/build-TouchCatch-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0-Debug/android-build/bin/AndroidManifest.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android'
     [aapt] 
     [aapt] /home/marcin/proj/touchcatch/build-TouchCatch-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0-Debug/android-build/bin/AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation').
     [aapt] 

BUILD FAILED
/home/marcin/devel/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/marcin/devel/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:694: null returned: 1

Total time: 0 seconds
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
13:14:10: The process "/home/marcin/devel/Qt5.5.0/5.5/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project TouchCatch (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.5.0))
```

How can I fix it? I can't use newer API since the device I have (GT-S6500D) has only Android 2.3.6

Answer (score 1):

I had to fix my AndroidManifest. API10 did not support some of the options.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208729/error-string-types-not-allowed-at-androidconfigchanges-in-manifest-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619974/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-hardwareaccelerated-when-building-w)

Answer (score 0):

May be related. On my system the /build-tools/24.0.0-preview was some how installed with the wrong hardware architecture.

Looking where its set, to set it to 23.0.3.